# How can I convert screen space to GUI Space/View Space?

Tags: unity, c#

Is there any way available to convert screen space into view space as like in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: So just to clarify, from the last image (right most) to the middle one?

Comment: yes as name given below

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know the values of `Camera.pixelWidth` and `Camera.pixelHeight`, you can get from the last picture to the middle one by simply dividing your ScreenSpace coordinates respectively by `Camera.pixelWidth` and `Camera.pixelHeight`.

```
Vector2 screenSpacePosition = new Vector2(100, 100);
Vector2 viewportSpacePosition = new Vector2(screenSpacePosition.X / Camera.pixelWidth, screenSpacePosition.Y / Camera.pixelHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` or `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`?
As you can guess from methods names, they are transforming screen position to world position, and vise versa.

The only thing you need to take into account is Z axis, which will be same to Z value of camera position.